# wrong memory locations when debugging in qemu with gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, qemu, osdev, gdbserver

I'm writing a little kernel in assembler. I'm running it in QEMU and have some problems with some bugs. Now I want to debug the kernel with dbg. So I assembled it like so:

```
$ nasm -g -f elf -o myos.elf myos.asm
$ objcopy --only-keep-debug myos.elf myos.sym
$ objcopy -O binary myos.elf myos.bin
```

Then I run it in QEMU with:

```
$ qemu-system-i386 -s -S myos.bin
```

Then I connect with gdb:

```
$ gdb
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
symbol-file myos.sym
Reading symbols from /home/sven/Projekte/myos/myos.sym...done.
```

I have a label named `welcome` in my kernel that points to a string. While testing I tried to look at that string, which gave the following result:

```
(gdb) x/32b welcome
0x1e <welcome>: 0x00    0xf0    0xa5    0xfe    0x00    0xf0    0x87    0xe9
0x26:   0x00    0xf0    0x6e    0xc9    0x00    0xf0    0x6e    0xc9
0x2e:   0x00    0xf0    0x6e    0xc9    0x00    0xf0    0x6e    0xc9
0x36:   0x00    0xf0    0x57    0xef    0x00    0xf0    0x6e
```

The label is defined like this:

```
welcome: db "System started. Happy hacking!", 10, 0
```

So you can see, gdb is pretending welcome starts with a null byte but by definition it's not. However the kernel uses the label correctly, so it doesn't seem like a poblem with my code. Examining other parts of the memory doesn't match the loaded kernel at all.

Does anyone know why the memory of the virtual machine doesn't match the loaded kernel, while the machine still behaves corectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation

- `qemu-system-i386` **loads the first byte of an x86 boot sector image file at address `0x7c00` at run time**.
- Your ELF files (`myos.elf`, `myos.sym`) mistakenly inform GDB that the code would be loaded at address 0. Thus GDB thinks `welcome` is at `0x1e` while it's actually at `0x7c1e`.
- Adding `0x7c00` to all addresses in GDB would work but is clumsy: `x/32xb (welcome + 0x7c00)`
- A better solution is to create an ELF file with the right addresses.

### Solution

**boot.asm**

```
; 'boot.asm'
; loaded by BIOS

[bits 16]

global main
main:
mov di, welcome
print_welcome:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, [di]
int 0x10
inc di
cmp byte [di], 0
jne print_welcome
hlt

db "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ; some padding to make welcome appear at 0x1e
welcome: db "System started. Happy hacking!", 10, 0

; x86 boot sector padding and signature
; NOTE: intentionally commented out. Will be added by linker script
;times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0x00
;db 0x55, 0xAA
```

**x86-boot.ld**

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        _text = .;
        *(.text);
        _text_end = .;
    }
    .data :
    {
        _data = .;
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON)
        _data_end = .;
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.note*);
        *(.iplt*);
        *(.igot*);
        *(.rel*);
        *(.comment);
/* add any unwanted sections spewed out by your version of gcc and flags here */
    }
}
```

Build the code with:

```
nasm -g -f elf -F dwarf boot.asm -o boot.o
cc -nostdlib -m32 -T x86-boot.ld -Wl,--build-id=none  boot.o -o boot
objcopy -O binary boot boot.good.bin
```

**dump-welcome.gdb**

```
target remote localhost:1234
symbol-file boot
monitor system_reset
# run until hlt instruction, address obtained through disassembly
until *0x7c0f
x/32xb welcome

monitor quit
disconnect
quit
```

Sample session:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S boot.good.bin &
$ gdb -q -x dump-welcome.gdb
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
main () at boot.asm:16
16  hlt
0x7c1e :   0x53    0x79    0x73    0x74    0x65    0x6d    0x20    0x73
0x7c26: 0x74    0x61    0x72    0x74    0x65    0x64    0x2e    0x20
0x7c2e: 0x48    0x61    0x70    0x70    0x79    0x20    0x68    0x61
0x7c36: 0x63    0x6b    0x69    0x6e    0x67    0x21    0x0a    0x00
```

### Thought Process

Most of the 32 bytes you dumped have values ≥ 0x80, i.e. **they're not printable ASCII characters**. This raises the question: **Am I *really* dumping the right address?**

The hex dump of your `welcome` message should be:

```
$ python -c 's = "System started. Happy hacking!"; print [hex(ord(x)) for x in s ]'
['0x53', '0x79', '0x73', '0x74', '0x65', '0x6d', '0x20', '0x73', '0x74', '0x61', '0x72', '0x74', '0x65', '0x64', '0x2e', '0x20', '0x48', '0x61', '0x70', '0x70', '0x79', '0x20', '0x68', '0x61', '0x63', '0x6b', '0x69', '0x6e', '0x67', '0x21']
```

Using GDB to search for the `welcome` message in memory would have revealed the right address as well:

```
(gdb) find 0, 0xffff, 'S', 'y', 's', 't'
0x7c1e
```

### Further Reading

- [GNU LD: Basic Linker Script Concepts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Basic-Script-Concepts.html#Basic-Script-Concepts): see discussion on LMA vs. VMA
- [Real mode in C with gcc : writing a bootloader](http://dc0d32.blogspot.tw/2010/06/real-mode-in-c-with-gcc-writing.html): source of the linker script above. Shows some cool GNU toolchain tricks for x86 real mode development.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now I wanted to look at the stack, but %sp is pointing at zeroes. Is there also some offset I have to deal with?

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu, `p $esp` in GDB should show `0x6f20` with the code in my answer. Post new question with complete source and GDB commands if you can't make it work.

Comment: Asked it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353268/sp-register-doesnt-point-to-stack?lq=1)